# Py2neo cypher query return instance method

Tags: neo4j, cypher, py2neo

Using the py2neo tutorial (http://book.py2neo.org/en/latest/cypher/):

```
    from py2neo import neo4j, cypher
    graph_db = neo4j.GraphDatabaseService()
    query = "START a=node(1) RETURN a"
    data, metadata = cypher.execute(graph_db, query)
    a = data[0][0]  # first row, first column
```

Trying to replicate this, I get:

```
>data[0][0]

Node('http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/1')
```

How do I get this to return the actual data, instead of the abstract information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Cypher query returns a node (`RETURN a`) and so that's what's being passed back: a `Node` object. If it's the node's properties that you need, you can either then inspect the properties on that node with the [get_properties](http://book.py2neo.org/en/latest/graphs_nodes_relationships/#py2neo.neo4j.Node.get_properties) method or return specific properties from the Cypher query instead (`RETURN a.name`).